# What kind of lens protector can I add to my Canon SX30

Tags: canon, point-and-shoot

Is there any lens protector that fits the Canon SX30?

Where can I buy it? I need to order it via Internet and be sent to Argentina.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the lens thread size is 67mm so any 67mm filter will do.  Annnd if you're looking for an inexpensive filter this question is discussing it:

[Where to buy cheap UV filters online?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4417/where-to-buy-cheap-uv-filters-online)